# Detecting when a player leaves a projectile and then removing entity

Tags: java, bukkit

I am building a 1.8.8 Bukkit/Spigot plugin that allows you to ride ender pearls and am stuck at detecting a dismount and removing the pearl. I have tried to catch the event but it doesn’t compile. I need a way to remove the pearl when there is a dismount. Thank you!

```
package damotheryeeter.general.enderpearlride.events;

import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import static org.bukkit.Material.ENDER_PEARL;
import org.bukkit.entity.EntityType;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.ProjectileLaunchEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;

public class EnderThrowEvent implements Listener {
@EventHandler
public void onThrow(final ProjectileLaunchEvent e) {
    if (e.getEntityType().equals(EntityType.ENDER_PEARL)) {
        if (!(e.getEntity().getShooter() instanceof Player)) return;
        if (((Player) e.getEntity().getShooter()).hasPermission("enderpearlride.ride")) {
            e.getEntity().setPassenger((Player) e.getEntity().getShooter());
            if (((Player) e.getEntity().getShooter()).hasPermission("enderpearlride.infinite")) {
                final Player p = (Player) e.getEntity().getShooter();
                final ItemStack[] pearl = {new ItemStack(ENDER_PEARL, 1)};
                p.getInventory().addItem(pearl);                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for that is:

```java
@EventHandler
public void onDismount(EntityDismountEvent e) {
    if(e.getEntity().getEntityType().equals(EntityType.ENDER_PEARL)) {
        e.getEntity().remove();
    }
}
```